# Support for Microsoft Visual Basic in the listings package

Tags: listings

Evidently the `listings` package does not support `Microsoft Visual Basic`. Are there any plans for `VB` in the future? Alternatively, are there any known work-arounds?

Comment: The `listings` package allows for the design of custom languages using the macro `\lstdefinelanguage`. Maybe someone has already made the effort?

Comment: [How to typeset VBA code in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22874/134144) may be interesting.

Comment: Can you explain your claim "evidently listings does not support VB"? Did you overlook _Basic (Visual)_ in the list of supported languages in the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (page 13)? Or do you know about this definition but you think the output is not satisfactory?

Comment: @Marijn I withdraw my claim, I missed the table on page 13: `\lstset{language=[Visual]Basic}` does the job. Thanks